# Linking agents takes too long with Workload Scheduler.

Tags: networking, workload-scheduler

Linking agents takes too long. This happens at JnextPlan and also when we manually administer the TWS network. Can _TWS_TRUSTED_ADDRESS solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should review your Netman log along with TWSMERGE to determine which addresses are being used during the links. If you see that the wrong address is being used then you can implement this solution.

There are two links established independently, one from the Master to the FTA and the other from the FTA to the Master.
.
The FTA will attempt to connect to the hostname IP address specified in the workstation definition for the Master. If this contains something that can always be correctly resolved by the Agent to the IP address of the correct NIC on the Master to connect to, then it is probably not necessary. However, where the Master has multiple NIC's, this generally is not the case.

Since both connections need to be established before the agent is considered to be fully linked, if there are delays linking from the agent to the Master while the Agent attempts to connect to the correct NIC on the Master, this can cause an established link from the Master to the agent to time out and be dropped, prolonging the time taken to link.

With the environment variable _TWS_TRUSTED_ADDRESS set, but undefined TWS will not request that the initial connection attempt is performed using a specific IP address.

**Resolving the issue.**

1) Shut and Stop the FTA
2) set the environment variable equal to the source address required.
3) Run StartUp on from the same shell where the environment variable is set.

The _TWS_TRUSTED_ADDRESS can be set in the following ways :-

1: the _TWS_TRUSTED_ADDRESS environment variable is unset first source address
is used according to IP address describing to node parameter on CPU definition,
then if it fails to communicate, source address is used according to OS setting.

2: the _TWS_TRUSTED_ADDRESS environment variable is set but without any value
source address is used according to OS setting.

3: the _TWS_TRUSTED_ADDRESS environment variable is set to a specific ip
address the specified source address is used.